# URL Rewrite Child Virtual Directory

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

Imagine I have this website:

```
http://localhost/site/admin
```

Where "site" is an IIS virtual directory and "admin" is an IIS virtual directory inside the "site" virtual directory. Both "site" and "admin" are separate websites so to speak, because one is say the main website and the other is like an admin portal. The problem I'm having is with the admin portal part of the URL.

Lets say I have an index.php which takes the name of the page to display, for example:

```
http://localhost/site/admin/index.php?p=cats
```

I used URL rewrite to allow the above URL to be written like this:

```
http://localhost/site/admin/cats
```

I just used the IIS rule wizard to create this kind of rule:

Pattern: `^([^/]+)/?$`
Action: `index.php?p={R:1}`

This works fine.

However I'm now trying to get to a URL such as this:

```
http://localhost/site/admin/cats/123
```

This would actually be:

```
http://localhost/site/admin/index.php?p=cats&id=123
```

I was trying to use a pattern such as this:

```
^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$
```

It seems that the URL works fine, but the side effect is that all my relative paths are now incorrect. What I want is:

```
http://localhost/site/admin/pages/header.php
```

But it ends up as:

```
http://localhost/site/admin/cats/pages/header.php
```

I think it's happening because the URL after being rewritten has "cats" after the "admin" part, but I can't figure out how to make this work properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you should at least do, is make sure you do not rewrite for existing pages / content (e.g. header.php). Also, you should URL Encode the parts you get from the URL. Without given it a thorough test, this should probably work:

```
<rule name="Rewrite">
    <match url="^(([^/]+)/)+([\w]+)/?([0-9]+)?$"/>
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
        </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?p={UrlEncode:{R:3}}&id={UrlEncode:{R:4}}"/>
</rule>
```